# EF Fluent API One-to-One relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to configure an optional-required simple relationship, but EF doesn't seem to scaffold the right migration:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string   FirstName   { get; set; }
    public string   LastName    { get; set; }
    public int ContactInfoId            { get; set; }
    public string PreferredCultureId    { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicantContact     Contact             { get; set; }
    public virtual Culture              PreferredCulture    { get; set; }
}




public ApplicantConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(a => a.Id);
    Property(a => a.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    Property(a => a.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

    HasOptional(a => a.Contact)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Applicant)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    HasOptional(a => a.PreferredCulture)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.PreferredCultureId);
}






CreateTable(
    "Main.Applicants",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            ContactInfoId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            PreferredCultureId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("General._Cultures", t => t.PreferredCultureId)
    .Index(t => t.PreferredCultureId);
```

Why is ContactInfoId is not being generated as a foreign key and nullable, as it is the optional side of the relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

In your domain class try

```
public class Applicant
{

    public string   FirstName   { get; set; }
    public string   LastName    { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicantContact     Contact             { get; set; }
    public virtual Culture              PreferredCulture    { get; set; }
}


public class ContactInfo
{
   // whatever contact info fields you have
}

public class Culture
{
  // culture fields
}
```

then in your context have

```
 public DbSet<ContactInfo> ContactInfos { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Culture> Cultures { get; set; }
```

The Id fields should get automatically if they are int.